# creating new relationship to a a resource in json api

Tags: drupal, many-to-many, relationship, json-api

I have room resource and inside room there are multiple features which are reference to this room. i am using subrequest to make changes to it but it does modify the relationships. here is my code:

```
const masterRequest = [

{
        requestId: "req-1",
       
        uri: `/jsonapi/node/room_type/123/relationships/field_feature`,
        action: "`delete`",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          data: {
            type: "paragraph--general_feature",
            id: "32542151",
          },
        }),

        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
          Accept: "application/vnd.api+json",
        },
      },

]


const response = await fetch(
      "https://example.com/subrequests",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(masterRequest),
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Basic ${credentials}`,
        },
      }
    );
```

how i can update relationships . i tried the method of json api docs but it does not work

```
PATCH /articles/1/relationships/tags HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json
Accept: application/vnd.api+json

{
  "data": [
    { "type": "tags", "id": "2" },
    { "type": "tags", "id": "3" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does Drupal support relationship links? I haven't found anything about it in Drupal's documentation.